# Unable to create list after upgrading 2013 to 2016 in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are able to create list using default master page.But the problem is with only custom master page we are not getting the template as we like.could any please help us.....

Comment: While developing custom masterpage you have missed some of the placeholder. Compare the placeholder in Seatle and your custom master page. You will get a missing placeholder into your custom master page

Comment: You should create new custom master page which will be functionally on SP2016